# How to find or detect last UN-Successful RUN command in Windows

Tags: windows-xp

I thought myself as expert in lots of things, before, when I tried to copy an amazing word that I hardly could remember.

But, the problem came when I was trying to open notepad and save that word
 (because I felt lazy to pick up my pen off the desk)
and in hurry I typed the word in RUN command (windows) and hit return key.

It struck me when I was expecting the notepad to open and later I was shown an error 
(due to incorrect command in run). 
This stroke made me forget the particular word that I was thinking of.

I had felt so confident that I spoke to myself and said

> "Oh! what have I done?  OK, no problem I can retrieve it because I had typed
>   it in run which can be recovered through the drop down menu"

Later, I couldn't recover it because I had directly typed it and NOT copied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

Comment: Are you sure you are not dreaming?

Comment: @Oded "Truth is bitter"
at first, I hesitated to ask this question because I thought I was expert and later felt bitter I couldn't solve it.
Finally with courage I've asked this question.

Like I said "Truth Is Bitter"

The problem is, everybody thinks themselves as an expert and tries to see the challenge (I had typed [expert only] with the question), and later they feel this bitter because they won't have any answer. 

That's why I've received four negative votes to my question (-4).
The fake experts should feel this question bitter. I expect it.

(am I expert?)
Regards

Comment: Your question is unintelligible, hence the downvotes. You are telling a tale of sorrow and woe on a site that needs facts and examples. Your tale is also rather off topic.

Comment: @OpenCode: "If you want honey, don't knock over the beehive." Good luck getting your answer after preventively insulting everyone.

Comment: I thought they took away Charlie Sheen's internet access. Next time why don't you just type 'notepad' in the search/run bar?

Comment: @Blomkvist :p for Charlie's internet access and thankyou for the suggestion for next time.

Comment: @Piskvor My intention was not like how you've described or understood

Comment: @Oded My question is simple "How to find or detect last UN-Successful RUN command in Windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type an non-existent program or file name into the run menu in Windows XP, you get the

```
Windows cannot find 'dfhhfdh'...
```

message, but the word is not lost - you are returned to the run dialog with the word still in it, selected.

To lose the word you would need to click OK on the warning message and then close the Run dialog or overtype its contents.

The reason you cannot retrieve it later is not the mode of input (pasted vs. typed), but because the command didn't successfully complete. Only commands which actually launch a program are saved in the Run menu's Most Recently Used items list.